# Конструктор массива классов

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть класс корабль, по-умолчанию он инициализируется параметром, который содержит в себя информацию о количестве палуб. Я пытаюсь инициализировать массив, вызвав конструктор, вот так:

```
Ship ship[SHIP_COUNT](DECK_X4);
```

Этот код естественно не проходит. И нельзя создать у него метод SetDeck, потому что это будет перечить логике создания кораблей (иначе размер можно будет менять постоянно).

Как можно создать массив класса, вызвав при этом для каждого элемента массива конструктор?

Comment: То есть класс не имеет конструктора по умолчанию?

Comment: Если значение SHIP_COUNT небольшое, то вы для каждого элемента массива можете указать инициализатор  в списке инициализации. Например, Ship ship[SHIP_COUNT] = { DECK_X4, DECK_X4, /*...*/ DECK_X4 };

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Судя по всему, кораблей в точности `SHIP_COUNT`. Дублировать знание количества кораблей количеством элементов списка как-то не комильфо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы уж пишете на C++, я бы посоветовал отказаться от сишных массивов, и пользоваться нормальными контейнерами.

Для `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Ship> ship;
ship.reserve(SHIP_COUNT);
for (int i = 0; i < SHIP_COUNT; i++)
    ship.emplace_back(DECK_X4);
```

---

Уточнение: как подсказывает @alexolut, в проектах RAD Studio есть возможность переключаться между старым и новым компиляторами (опция *classic compiler* в свойствах проекта). Стандарт C++11 поддерживается лишь новым компилятором, поэтому если в проекте используется старый, нужно воспользоваться

```
push_back(Ship(DECK_X4));
```

вместо `emplace_back`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34279/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---).

Comment: Если в комментариях появились какие-то уточнения к ответу — пожалуйста, перенесите их в сам ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Если значение `SHIP_COUNT` не велико, то вы могли бы указать инициализатор для каждого элемента массива либо как

```
Ship ship[SHIP_COUNT] = { DECK_X4, DECK_X4, /*...*/, DECK_X4 };
```

если конструктор является преобразующим конструктором, либо как

```
Ship ship[SHIP_COUNT] = { Ship( DECK_X4 ), Ship( DECK_X4 ), /*...*/, Ship( DECK_X4 ) };
```

если конструктор объявлен со спецификатором `explicit`.

Иначе вам потребуется объявить конструктор по умолчанию с аргументом по умолчанию, как, например,

```
Ship( TypeOfDeck value = DECK_X4 );
```

Либо вы можете использовать контейнер `std::vector<Ship>` следующим образом:

```
std::vector<Ship> ship( SHIP_COUNT, DECK_X4 );
```

Или

```
std::vector<Ship> ship( SHIP_COUNT, Ship( DECK_X4 ) );
```

опять-таки в зависимости от того, объявлен ли конструктор со спецификатором функции `explicit` или без него.

Comment: Ругается на строчку с объявлением вектора  Type name expected

Comment: @T2skler Вам надо включить заголовок #include <vector>

Comment: Уже есть и using namespace std;

Comment: Все, исправил, случайно выставил имя вектора, как имя класса в котором он находится Ships Ships

Answer (score 4):

Т.к количество палуб является неизменной величиной, то использование `std::vector` избыточно и совершенно не нужно. С другой стороны, использование обычного статического массива не удобно, поэтому на выручку приходит `std::array` который обладает всеми преимуществами стандартного контейнера, при этом оставаясь незименяемым:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //...
    std::array<Ship, SHIP_COUNT> ship;
    std::fill(ship.begin(), ship.end(), DECK_X4);
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ТС так и не признался в комментариях, есть ли у него конструктор по умолчанию.

Comment: Об обратном - тоже ни кто не пишет.